# How can I construct my grep command on zsh to return a specific value?

Tags: terminal, command-line, catalina, zsh

I am trying to use the command line to extract a specific value from a web page.

The page is from the VS Code marketplace: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HCLTechnologies.hclappscancodesweep and I am after the number of installs. 
I managed to get to a point where I can isolate up to this:

```
{"statisticName":"install","value":206.0},{"statisticName":"averagerating","value":5.0},{"statisticName":"ratingcount","value":8.0},{"statisticName":"trendingdaily","value":0.0},{"statisticName":"trendingmonthly","value":88.950276243093924},{"statisticName":"trendingweekly","value":28.7292817679558},{"statisticName":"weightedRating","value":4.668447071838485}],"installationTargets":[{"target":"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Code","targetVersion":""}],"deploymentType":0}
```

I am on a mac and using zsh. The command I'm currently using is:

`curl -G "https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HCLTechnologies.hclappscancodesweep" | grep -Eo {\"statisticName\":\"install\",\"value\":.+\}`

The desired output of this command should be: 
`206.0` which is the number I'm after. If you can trim it down to `206` that's even better.

I have 2 main problems:
1) I can't isolate the match to start right before my number. I tried `\K` but that doesn't seem to work on the mac. I did not see an option to use groups either.

2) I can't make the matching after my number stop after the first match of a curly bracket `}`. Keep in mind the number can vary in length, so I want to stop it where the JSON stops. 
I did actually try using `[:digit:]` and `[0-9]` to restrict to the number, but that did not work either and that's why I went down the curly bracket path.

I did see some options out there to work with the JSON part and extract things there, but the environment I'm working with does not have the flexibility of installing other utilities, so I need help to achieve this with a "vanilla" environment.

P.S. I'm working on Catalina 10.15.4

Comment: So turns out piping in sed was the easier way of doing this. The command now looks like this: curl -G "https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HCLTechnologies.hclappscancodesweep" | grep -Eo {\"statisticName\":\"install\",\"value\":.+\} | sed -E 's/.*"install","value":"?([^,"]*)}"?.*/\1/'

Comment: I had the grep to isolate part of my JSON and since I'm not that good with sed, decided to use only a sample that extracts the number I wanted from the grep output. Elegant? No. Does it do the job? Yes.

Comment: FWIW Your _command_ does not work for me, it returns nothing at all; however, this works for me: `curl -sG "https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HCLTechnologies.hclappscancodesweep" | grep -Eom 1 '[0-9]+[ ]installs' | awk '{print $1}'`

Comment: Please include your own solution in the question, post it as an answer below instead. And actually it will even work if you omit the `grep` part :-)

Comment: I did realise later on that parsing directly for that JSON would do the trick. Thanks for pointing me that way, learned something new today!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`grep` isn't well suited for data scrapping, you are better of with `sed` in such cases.

```
curl -sG 'https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HCLTechnologies.hclappscancodesweep' \
    | sed -Ene 's/.*\"install\",\"value\":([0-9\.]+).*/\1/p'
```

The first part of the substition matches only once in the HTML file so there isn't even a need to select the correct line first.

To get the number without the decimal point use

```
curl -sG 'https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HCLTechnologies.hclappscancodesweep' \
    | sed -Ene 's/.*\"install\",\"value\":([0-9]+).*/\1/p'
```

Comment: FWIW Your command does not work for me, it returns nothing at all; however, this works for me: `curl -sG "https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HCLTechnologies.hclappscancodesweep" | grep -Eom 1 '[0-9]+[ ]installs' | awk '{print $1}'` What's interesting is it  appears what's returned by `curl` using the same **URL** is different for the OP then what's returned for me.

Comment: @user3439894 Interesting. I just copy/pasted the commands form my answer back into Terminal, they still work here -)

Comment: @user3439894 Location-depending content on the web page maybe? Both the OP and I are connecting from Europe, maybe the page looks different in the States.

Comment: I'm sure it does as I know you wouldn't post something that doesn't work, but the only explanation I have is I'm not getting back the same content as you or the OP from the `curl` cmd for the same **URL**. I wonder why that is?

Comment: I just noticed a **Sign in** for that page, are you signed in? I'm not.

Comment: @user3439894 Me neither. The HTML I get is at https://gist.github.com/nohillside/6ee109add870a8db0f6e59446281ed73 now.

Comment: I just tried this and it does indeed work for me. I get the right number from the CLI. Marked it as correct since you pointed me to ```sed``` in the comments to my question.

Comment: It's very weird that it doesn't work for you... Are you using zsh? Any chance you might have another version of CURL (i use w/e comes on the mac) that gets you a different response? They are definitely different responses.

Comment: @sir_k, This is what's returned for me using default `curl` with `zsh` in **macOS Catalina 10.15.4**: https://paste.ee/p/cbOKk

Comment: @user3439894 Ah. The one sir_k and I get ends with (C) 2020, yours with (C) 2019. Time to flush some caches?

Comment: This is the first time I went to that **URL**, so no cache on my system! We are getting served two different pages from the same **URL** and it's beyond our control.